# Extract file based on pattern in bash

Tags: bash, shell, logfile

I have a log file which contains date time and then report for each error. Each error starts with date time pattern. I am getting an id as parameter in shell script and want to put the error report with corresponding id to a new file. I am new to bash and tried it using grep and cut, but grep doesn't take more than 1 character. Also reading line by line and searching the key isn't feasible as id is present 2-3 line after error report for the particular id starts. Help me! Thanks.

Below is example of log.

```
    2015-09-25 03:34:40 ................<event>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <msg>.......: ErrorName1 ===
    ............
    ..........
    .....
    </event>

    2015-09-25 03:34:42 .................<event>
    <id>yyy</id>
    <msg>.......: ErrorName2 ===
    ............
    ..........
    .....
    </event>
```

EDIT: All errors do not have same number of lines and some of the events have same error id. So if I request for particular error id, all these events with same error id should be put in different files

Comment: what are the output files supposed to be named as ?

Comment: what will be the content of output file?

Comment: @amdixon output file should be named as error name, which is written in report before <event>

Comment: @ShravanYadav output file should be starting from date time to </event>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This helps you for catching id xxx by reading `inputfile` and dumps the matching result to `outputfile`</strike>

```
grep -Poz '(?s)^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*?<event>.*?<id>xxx</id>.*?</event>' inputfile > outputfile
```

From the man of grep

```
-o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts  of  a  matching  line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.

-z, --null-data
          Treat  the  input  as  a set of lines, each terminated by a zero
          byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.   Like  the
          -Z  or --null option, this option can be used with commands like
          sort -z to process arbitrary file names.
-P, --perl-regexp
              Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  This is  highly  experimental  and
              grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

> (?s) - makes a match across multiline

---

### Edit

I made bash script for your problem and here it is. You need to pass the input file as the first argument and id of the event as the second argument to the script. It saves your log to different files for each event. I hope you benefit from this. I could not find a solution other than reading line by line.

```
#!/bin/bash
inputfile="$1"
ID="$2"
let found=0
let counter=1
cumul=""

function searchevent(){

    output=$(echo "$cumul" | grep -Poz "(?s)^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*?<event>.*?<id>$ID</id>.*?</event>" 2>/dev/null)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "$output" >> "outputfile_""$ID""_$counter.log"
        let counter++
    fi
}
while read line; do
    if echo "$line" | grep -P '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}' &>/dev/null
    then
        let found++
    fi
    if [ "$found" -eq 1 ]
    then
        cumul="$cumul"$'\n'"$line"
    else
        if [ "$found" -eq 2 ]
        then
            searchevent
            let found=1
            cumul="$line"
        fi
    fi
done < "$inputfile"

if [ "$found" -eq 1 ]
then
    searchevent
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. But this puts all events with same request id in same output file. What should I do to get these in different files. Also, the filename should be ErrorName. I have given the pattern for ErrorName in file. It would be great if you could help on this too. Thanks

Comment: I had posted the answer before you edited and told us that ids were not unique, sorry about that. I tried many ways however I could not find such a good way to iterate over matched groups with your current input format and I failed not including other events ids. using "sed" and processing line by line may be easier to implement.

Comment: I am thinking of using for loop and keeping each id in a separate file and then again splitting using date time into separate files.

Comment: there is a little issue here as this script starts from encountering first date time, and ends at </event> whose error id is xxx. So, all the errors before the specific error are also printed.

Comment: Let me check and improve it today, if i can. If there is a chance to use python language instead of bash, it would be much easier

Comment: Thanks alot for the effort. A little slow though but works correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're really 'splitting' the file. According to your description you're trying to extract a part of it given some id. If each of your events has the same number of lines (like in your example data), you'll be good with:

```
<your_file grep -B 1 -A 5 '<id>your_id</id>'
```

Where `-A n` means n lines **a**fter the match, `-B n` means n lines **b**efore the match.

Answer (score 0):

awk can help.

```
awk '{if ($0~/"<event>"/)k=1;if (k==1)print $0;if ($0~/"</event>"/)k=0}' inputfile > outputfile
```